# Access Query & Email assistance

Tags: loops, email, ms-access, report, criteria

I'm decent when it comes to working with Access, and can usually figure things out but am currently stumped on this query process.

I only have 2 shipment tables. One contains historical data (tblBookedLoads), while the second table (RMCData) contains current orders.

What I need to do, is for each row in RMCData, figure out who has driven the same route recently (Origin to Destination) and send them an email with the details of the matching shipments... and any others that match, IE, if I have 50 shipments from Atlanta to Memphis tomorrow, I don't want to send them 50 emails.

I'm just not sure about how to go about retrieving the information since it it stored in different formats, or how to create a query based on row by row data from fields in another table... Let me know what you think. I'm guessing it has something to do with looping in  vba, but not sure.

Both tables are read only.

---

tblRMCData          'Contains details for new orders (approx. 1000 rows)
' has fields 'ReferenceNum','Ship Date','Origin City', 'Origin State','Origin Zip','destination', 'Weight','Comments","Comments2"

'Origin/Destination City, State and Zip are separated

---

tblBookedLoads      'contains history of orders (approx. 20000 rows). CONTAINS DUPLICATES
' has fields 'Carrier', 'Ship Date", 'Order','Origin', 'Destination','Weight','Bill Amount",'email address'
' Origin/Destination is populated as "LITTLE ROCK, AR 12345"

---

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired output should be provided as text tables in question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'tables are read only' - If data is in Access, how are tables read only?